# Get value from cURL XML

Tags: php, xml, curl

I fetch data from an XML feed using cURL. I need to get a specific value from the XML.

[The XML feed is here](http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_sko.cgi?ico=61385701).

I need the text: *Gymnázium Christiana Dopplera* (`<D:Nazev>`)

I've tried using `DOMDocument`, but I get a "Fatal error".
What am I doing wrong?

```
if ($curl = curl_init("http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_sko.cgi?ico=61385701")) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom = loadXML($content);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("Nazev");
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function loadXML() in C:\www\pokusy\ares\index.php on line 13

Comment: Have you tried [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)? [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)? Show us what you've already tried.

Comment: I tried DOMDocument but It was not work correct. http://paste.ofcode.org/AUdrbdnGAAxgWEy4xpqx3C. Error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function loadXML() in C:\www\pokusy\ares\index.php on line 13**

Comment: Please add what you have tried to the question itself rather than comments so others are more likely to see it and use it to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) will convert the entire XML document into a object and you can go from there.

Comment: I tried it, but I do not know how I get tag which I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMDocument`, as you've stated, in the following way:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("Nazev") as $item)
  echo 'Value: '.$item->nodeValue.'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: It look good, but it returns more values. I need only one: Gymnázium Christiana Dopplera

Comment: Right, because your XML contains multiple Nazev items.

Comment: And is any way to get the only one that I need?

Comment: How would you know which one you need and what's the difference between this one and the others? Look at the XML, study its structure, and figure out what exactly is it you're looking for.